# Image Processing for Knitted fabric

Tags: image-processing, edge-detection

I want to calculate the wales and courses (vertical rows and horizontal rows of loops) of this fabric in the image using image processing. How can I do it? Please help me.

[Knitted fabric](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmIc0.jpg)

Comment: Please provide us with the code on which you worked so we can help you in a better way.

Comment: The repeated pattern makes me think of Fourrier analysis (FFT) to detect frequencies of repeated patterns. You could try copying a chunk of the image and then sliding it left to right across and then up and down over the image to find where the Normalised Cross Correlation is high and how often it repeats.

Comment: Can't you count manually on a small sample and extrapolate to the whole area ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know my wales from my courses, or my plains from my purls, and I haven't had my first coffee yet this morning, so be warned...

I am using **ImageMagick** which is installed on most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows. You just type commands into the Terminal.

You can extract a 100x100 pixel patch from the top-left (0,0) of your image like this:

```
convert knitting.jpg -crop 100x100+0+0 extract.jpg
```

[image]

You can then use a *"sub-image search"* to slide that extract across the surface of your image and find where it correlates well (i.e. matches). The result is another image which is brighter proportionally to the match, and dark where the match is poor.

```
compare -metric RMSE -subimage-search knitting.jpg extract.jpg locations.png
```

That gives you this `"locations-0.png"` which shows you the best match:

[image]

which is obviously perfect as that is where I cut the extract from. It also outputs this `"locations-1.png"` which shows you the match quality at each point:

[image]

If I disable the transparency, stretch the contrast and threshold that like this:

```
convert locations-1.png -alpha off -normalize -threshold 80% matches.png
```

[image]

I guess you can do peak-detection or other processing if this approach seems to locate the wales and courses and things you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much friend. I expect to use python - OpenCV for this task. Have you any idea about that?

Comment: It's just the same except it's called *"Template Matching"*, look here https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html